# JAVA. Как избежать опустошения массива в массиве при использовании .clear()

Tags: java, arraylist

1. Задаю значения для первого массива.
2. Добавляю первый массив во второй массив.
3. Очищаю первый массив.
4. Массив внутри массива тоже очищается, но почему, я ведь его не трогаю?

Пример

```
// массив строк
ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>();  

// массив с массивами строк
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array2 = new ArrayList<>();

// добавляем в первый массив две строки
array1.add("Строка_1");
array1.add("Строка_2");
// добавляем первый массив с двумя стоками во второй массив
array2.add(array1);
// очищаем первый массив от ранее добавленных строк
array1.clear();
// проверим кол-во строк в массиве, который был добавлен в массив 
int size = array2.get(0).size();

// size будет равно нулю, значит массив внутри массива тоже очистился, но почему ?
// как очистить array1 не затрагивая array2 ?
```

Comment: Ответа я пока не нашел,
но зато нашел способ при котором этого можно избежать - использовать обычные массивы вместо Array List.
При их обнулении такого безобразия не наблюдается.

Это не панацея, конечно, но в моем конкретном случае не нужно менять размер массива по ходу работы и обычный массив с фиксированной длиной меня устроит.

А вот что делать если все-же нужен именно ArrayList ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут дело в том, что вы оперируете со ссылками на объект, содержащий список строк. Т.е. когда вы создали первый список строк (array1), то вы создали в памяти массив и теперь можете обращаться к нему по ссылке, находящейся в переменной array1.

После этого вы создали в памяти ещё один список-массив и в его первую ячейку поместили переменную `array1`. Но, т.к. эта переменная суть ссылка, то вы не создали новый массив в памяти, а лишь указали из какой области памяти второй массив должен брать значения. Теперь у вас есть две ссылки на один и тот же объект в памяти.

Поэтому, когда вы очищаете значения в памяти через ссылку array1, то и вторая ссылка, `array2.get(0)` будет показывать пустой массив, т.к. она отображает всё тот же что и `array1` участок памяти.

Если вам нужно, чтобы во втором массиве создался новый объект в памяти вместо ссылки на уже существующий вам нужно явно создать новый объект в памяти. Например так:

```
array2.add(new ArrayList<>(array1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот эта строка

```
int size = array2.get(0).size();
```

Означает взять содержимое первой ячейки массива (это ваш вложенный массив) и вызвать у объекта в этой ячейки `size()`. Т.е. вы берете размер вложенного массива.

```
int size = array2.size();
```

Вот эта строка вернет 1.

`ArrayList` - это объектный тип. При добавлении его в другую коллекцию - добавляется только ссылка. Если вы хотите получить копию, то надо сделать вот так

```
array2.add(new ArrayList<>(array1));
```